# How to force :hover on DOM element?

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of questions exactly like this and all of them answer the same - **just add class** and toggle it. **Not in my case**.

Scenario:

When my page scrolls, I duplicate the table's first column and attach it with `position:fixed` to the left of the browser which makes me see the headers when table is wide.

Original table has css with `:hover` like this:

```
table tr:hover td { background: red }
```

This is great as I can see the whole row highlighted when I hover it, but not so great that
if I hover the cloned table it highlights only this one column. I would like to force :hover state on original table by **not adding any class.**

What I have tried so far without any effect:

```
 - .trigger('mouseover');
 - .trigger('mouseenter');
 - .trigger('hover');
 - .hover()
 - .mouseenter();
 - .mouseover();
```

Comment: When you say "force hover state", do you mean that when you hover over a row in the cloned table you want the corresponding row in the original table to behave as if you're hovering over it at the same time? Why are you so opposed to adding a class?

Comment: Why would adding a class not be an option here? The two tables aren't connected. The only way to bridge this is to detect the hover on one, then add the class on the other.

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, I want to apply it with JS

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer because I want to alter as little code as possible :)

Comment: It's not much of a change, just change your CSS to `table tr:hover td, table tr.hover td { background: red }` and then about five lines of `jQuery` is all it'll take to add and remove the new `hover` class from the original table rows in response to hovering over the cloned rows.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks. I have used this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not possible to trigger a CSS pseudoclass from JQuery/Javascript as far as I know.
There is little to no alternative other than working with JS/JQuery events, as you've been doing, and CSS classes.

Comment: Thanks. It seems really I will have to modify some more code than I intended to :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can force clicked state with `document.getElementById("ElementID").click();`